# Выравнивание битовых полей

Tags: qt, структуры, выравнивание

Добрый день. Имеется такая проблема. Есть переменная, отвечающая за координаты X и Y, которая должна занимать в памяти 3 байта, т.е. в разрядах 0-11 содержится значение координаты X, а в разрядах 12-23 - значение координаты Y. И так несколько таких переменных записываются в QByteArray друг за другом. Создал структуру:

```
struct TCoord {
    quint16 xCoord:12;
    quint16 yCoord:12;
};
```

Но если посмотреть размер этой структуры, то он равен 4 байтам. В Linux помогает использование `__attribute__(__packed__)`, в Windows с компилятором VS такое конечно же не прокатывает. `#pragma pack(push,1)` тоже ничем не помогает. Подскажите как упаковать такую структуру до 3 байт. Или подскажите еще какой-нибудь способ хранить два значения размером по 1,5 байта в 3-х байтовой переменной. Использую Qt 4.8.

Comment: Подозреваю, что никак, поскольку битовое поле не может пересекать границу содержащего его типа. Можно было бы применить uint32, тогда (наверное) выравнивания полей будут желаемыми, но размер будет всё равно 4, а не 3.

Comment: http://ideone.com/QHLnva & http://ideone.com/aByXkA

Answer (score 1):

А к чему такая тесная упаковка структуры? Если при хранении в файле действительно присутствует выигрыш по объёму, то работа с такой структурой в *оперативной* памяти сильно просадит производительность.

Оптимальное решение (если подобная экономия действительно связана с работой с файлами) таково. **При загрузке из файла «растаскивайте» поля по полноценно выровненным структурам, а при записи запаковывайте их обратно.**

Если же упаковка вызвана простым желанием сокращения потребления оперативной памяти, бросайте экономию «на спичках»! Сокращение записи на один байт даст не более килобайта экономии, зато (повторюсь) больно ударит по производительности.

Компилятор выравнивает поля и переменные для ускорения работы с ними. В данном случае *просто чтение и запись* неупакованных полей будут значительно быстрее, чем *чтение — сдвиг — логическое И — модификация — сдвиг обратно — объединение по ИЛИ с предыдущим значением по маске* упакованных.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом. Создаю QBitArray, записываю в него координаты. Размер его при этом составляет также 4 байта. Непосредственно перед самими данными в начале битового массива появляется еще один байт. Может мне кто-нибудь объяснить, что именно записано в этом байте? А при попытке записать через QDataStream этот битовый массив в QByteArray появляются еще 3 лишних байта в начале. Читал здесь http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html, но так и не понял, что в них пишется. Поэтому создал массив quint8 из 3-х элементов и с помощью сдвигов заполняю его из битового массива. Если кто подскажет более красивое решение, буду рад.